# Найти 2 элемента массива, сумма которых равна заданному числу JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, функции, ecmascript-6

Дан массив из чисел Фибоначчи, дано некоторое число X, нужно написать программу, которая найдет в массиве все пары целых чисел, сумма которых равна заданному значению(X), и вывести true иначе вывести false.

Пример А

Если нам дали массив Фибоначчи [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13,] и значение 12, функция вернет false, потому что никакие Два числа из массива не могут дать 12 в сумме.

Пример Б

Но если этот массив Фибоначчи [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21,] и значение 22, функция должна вернуть true, потому что 21 + 1 = 22.

```js
function fib(n) {
  let arr = [0, 1];
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    arr.push(arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2])
  }
  console.log(arr);
  return arr[n];
}

function f(n, arr) {
  return arr.some((i) => arr.includes(n - i));
}

console.log(fib(8));
console.log(f(20, [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]));
```

Comment: вернет. А какой вопрос то?

Comment: function f(n, arr) {
  return arr.some((i) => arr.includes(n - i));
}                            этот часть кода как можно по другому написать???

Comment: Можно, а смысл?

Comment: просто интересно как можно получить тот же результат по другому

Comment: Ваша функция не находит «Все пары целых чисел» (c) однако)

Comment: Если массив большой (числа повторяются), из него можно `Set` сделать, и `has`-ом проверять.

Comment: Если немного подумать, то такая пара ровно одна (если вообще есть) и одно из чисел пары это ближайшее снизу к X число Фибоначчи

Comment: @AlexeyTen, если `0` входит, как в некоторых примерах в вопросе, то пар уже две

Comment: Ну да. Я просто по привычке не считаю ноль числом фибоначчи

Comment: `10 = 5 + 5` в ответ должно попасть?

Answer (score 0):

```
function fibonacci(n){
        let arr = [0, 1];
        for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++){
          arr.push(arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2])
        }
        return arr;
     }
  
       let array = fibonacci(21);
       let inputNum = +prompt('Input Number: 1 - 10000', '');

       function func(num, arr) {
         for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
           if (arr[i] + arr[j] == num) {
             console.log(arr[i],'+',arr[j],'=', num);
             console.log(arr);
                return true;
           }
         }
       }
            console.log(num, arr);
               return false;
     }
         console.log(func(inputNum, array));
```